# PowerShell script to create a site in IIS with Reverse Proxy to eg. http://localhost:9001

Tags: powershell, iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I am trying to automate deployment of our .NET 5 GenericHost services. As they have both a WebAPI and long-running processes, IMHO it makes sense to deploy them as Windows Services and then create a IIS site that acts as reverse proxy. In short:

```
Browser ---------------------> IIS site -----------------------> WindowsService
         https:/somesite.com             http://localhost:9001
```

My "only" problem in this setup is how to create the reverse-proxy IIS site using PowerShell. I have absolute zero experience with this part.

I have figured out, that the IIS Module for PowerShell must be used. But I can't see if it gives access to `URL Rewrite 2`, which is the way I know how to do reverse proxy in IIS.

Anybody know about the right documentation for this?

Comment: There is really no need to include IIS in the picture any more. .NET is already mature enough to work as reverse proxy alone, https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy You can save quite a lot of footprint by removing IIS/Windows and simply host everything in a small Linux container.

Comment: As it happens we have just taken the first steps to go exactly in that direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the PowerShell WebAdministration Module can be used to edit Rewrite configuration

Example to edit a global rule:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules/rule[@name='Test']/match" -name "url" -value "foobar"
```

I would use the `Configuration Editor` in `IIS Manager` to create the rules and then use the `Generate Script` feature in the Actions pane to create a PowerShell script which you can then use elsewhere.

Comment: I will try that - thank you.